# Realtek RTS5129 Card Reader not working

Tags: release-hera, drivers

I am using elementary OS on acer Swift 3 SF314-55g. It has a Realtek card reader in it, but when I insert an SD card into it nothing happens.

Here is the output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b5c5 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HD WebCam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1c7a:0570 LighTuning Technology Inc. EgisTec Touch Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So the system does recognize it but it does not work for some reason.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the steps in the link below and my card reader started working.
https://github.com/asymingt/rts5139